# Python - Move and overwrite files and folders

Tags: python, file, move, overwrite

I have a directory, 'Dst Directory', which has files and folders in it and I have 'src Directory' which also has files and folders in it. What I want to do is move the contents of 'src Directory' to 'Dst Directory' and overwrite any files that exist with the same name. So for example 'Src Directory\file.txt' needs to be moved to 'Dst Directory\' and overwrite the existing file.txt. The same applies for some folders, moving a folder and merging the contents with the same folder in 'dst directory'

I'm currently using `shutil.move` to move the contents of src to dst but it won't do it if the files already exist and it won't merge folders; it'll just put the folder inside the existing folder.

Update: To make things a bit clearer, what I'm doing is unzipping an archive to the Dst Directory and then moving the contents of Src Directory there and rezipping, effectively updating files in the zip archive. This will be repeated for adding new files or new versions of files etc which is why it needs to overwrite and merge

Comment: Note that [`distutils.dir_util.copy_tree`](https://docs.python.org/dev/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.dir_util.copy_tree) is not able to copy special files, e.g. [named pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) (throws `distutils.errors.DistutilsFileError`).

Comment: There's also `os.replace()` function, see also [Move file and overwrite existing in Python 3.6 on Windows - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48709540/move-file-and-overwrite-existing-in-python-3-6-on-windows)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use `copy()` instead, which is willing to overwrite destination files. If you then want the first tree to go away, just `rmtree()` it separately once you are done iterating over it.

http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy

http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree

**Update:**

Do an `os.walk()` over the source tree. For each directory, check if it exists on the destination side, and `os.makedirs()` it if it is missing. For each file, simply `shutil.copy()` and the file will be created or overwritten, whichever is appropriate.

Comment: copy() can't copy folders though, can it?

Comment: No, but `move()` on each file also does not create the destination directories, so I assumed that your code already did an `os.makedirs()` on destination folders that did not exist. Ah! I think I understand now — you were doing a `move()` on the *whole* tree at once? Gotchya. Will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update, the problem with that is that the files to copy are always changing (new files added etc.) so I'd have to update the code every time I added new files for moving, if you understand that. Anyway, I managed it with distutils.dir_util.copy_tree(src, dst) which copys the folders and files and overwrites/merges where neccesary, thanks for the help

Comment: `os.walk()` gives you a fresh listing of the source files each time it runs, so it's okay if the list changes each time, if I understand your question. But good luck with the `distutils` solution, though — it's always an adventure when someone depends on `distutils` rather than the stdlib! I suspect they'll keep that function working, though.

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't really understand the os.walk method, I assumed you'd have to define the files to copy with shutil.copy. I understand it now, haven't been using os.walk for very long. I'll correct answer this then as I can see it works but I'll stick with distutils for now becuase of the simplicity

Comment: `copy()` won't overwrites read only files

Answer (score 74):

This will go through the source directory, create any directories that do not already exist in destination directory, and move files from source to the destination directory:

```
import os
import shutil

root_src_dir = 'Src Directory\\'
root_dst_dir = 'Dst Directory\\'

for src_dir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_src_dir):
    dst_dir = src_dir.replace(root_src_dir, root_dst_dir, 1)
    if not os.path.exists(dst_dir):
        os.makedirs(dst_dir)
    for file_ in files:
        src_file = os.path.join(src_dir, file_)
        dst_file = os.path.join(dst_dir, file_)
        if os.path.exists(dst_file):
            # in case of the src and dst are the same file
            if os.path.samefile(src_file, dst_file):
                continue
            os.remove(dst_file)
        shutil.move(src_file, dst_dir)
```

Any pre-existing files will be removed first (via `os.remove`) before being replace by the corresponding source file. Any files or directories that already exist in the destination but not in the source will remain untouched.

Comment: That is nice, thanks for that! I think that's what Brandon Craig Rhodes was talking about, but thanks for providing a snippet! Unfortunately you can't have two correct answers ^^

Comment: And to copy them over is as easy as replacing "shutil.move" with "shutil.copy".

Comment: If root_dst_dir == 'dir1\\dir2\\', os.mkdir(dst_dir) would throw an error saying "No such file or directory: 'dir1\\dir2\\'". Use os.makedirs(dst_dir) can avoid this problem.

Comment: This is a problem: `src_dir.replace(root_src_dir, root_dst_dir)`. Consider some directory 'a' being merged into directory 'b'. If there is a subdirectory `a/hahaha`, it will be moved to `b/hbhbhb`. You need `src_dir.replace(root_src_dir, root_dst_dir, 1)` to ensure you only do the first replacement.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the fixes pointed out by @lyen and myself. This solution has worked quite well for me. Thanks!

Comment: How to delete the empty directories in the root_src_dir? I get Errorno 16 when using rmdir

Comment: This works as of Python 3.8

Answer (score 10):

Since none of the above worked for me, so I wrote my own recursive function. Call Function copyTree(dir1, dir2) to merge directories. Run on multi-platforms Linux and Windows.

```
def forceMergeFlatDir(srcDir, dstDir):
    if not os.path.exists(dstDir):
        os.makedirs(dstDir)
    for item in os.listdir(srcDir):
        srcFile = os.path.join(srcDir, item)
        dstFile = os.path.join(dstDir, item)
        forceCopyFile(srcFile, dstFile)

def forceCopyFile (sfile, dfile):
    if os.path.isfile(sfile):
        shutil.copy2(sfile, dfile)

def isAFlatDir(sDir):
    for item in os.listdir(sDir):
        sItem = os.path.join(sDir, item)
        if os.path.isdir(sItem):
            return False
    return True


def copyTree(src, dst):
    for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        d = os.path.join(dst, item)
        if os.path.isfile(s):
            if not os.path.exists(dst):
                os.makedirs(dst)
            forceCopyFile(s,d)
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            isRecursive = not isAFlatDir(s)
            if isRecursive:
                copyTree(s, d)
            else:
                forceMergeFlatDir(s, d)
```

Comment: What's scenarios didn't work for you when using other answers?

Comment: Worth noting, if src has a file with the same name as a directory in dst, this solution will put the file inside the directory that shares its name, while [Ray Vega's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7420617/331041) will throw `OSError: [Errno 21] Is a directory`.

Comment: This worked perfect. No OSError 10/12/16/21 ... I got so many errors trying the sys.move(). Thank you .

Answer (score 9):

You can use this to copy directory overwriting existing files:

```py
import shutil
shutil.copytree("src", "dst", dirs_exist_ok=True)
```

`dirs_exist_ok` argument was added in Python 3.8.

See docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree

Answer (score 6):

If you also need to overwrite files with read only flag use this:

```
def copyDirTree(root_src_dir,root_dst_dir):
"""
Copy directory tree. Overwrites also read only files.
:param root_src_dir: source directory
:param root_dst_dir:  destination directory
"""
for src_dir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_src_dir):
    dst_dir = src_dir.replace(root_src_dir, root_dst_dir, 1)
    if not os.path.exists(dst_dir):
        os.makedirs(dst_dir)
    for file_ in files:
        src_file = os.path.join(src_dir, file_)
        dst_file = os.path.join(dst_dir, file_)
        if os.path.exists(dst_file):
            try:
                os.remove(dst_file)
            except PermissionError as exc:
                os.chmod(dst_file, stat.S_IWUSR)
                os.remove(dst_file)

        shutil.copy(src_file, dst_dir)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at: [`os.remove`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.remove) to remove existing files.

Comment: Problem with that is that the files I want to add to the folder will change (new ones will be added and old ones updated) so I can't have a set list of what to remove, thanks though

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I wanted to move files and folder structures and overwrite existing files, but not delete anything which is in the destination folder structure.

I solved it by using `os.walk()`, recursively calling my function and using `shutil.move()` on files which I wanted to overwrite and folders which did not exist.

It works like `shutil.move()`, but with the benefit that existing files are only overwritten, but not deleted.

```
import os
import shutil

def moverecursively(source_folder, destination_folder):
    basename = os.path.basename(source_folder)
    dest_dir = os.path.join(destination_folder, basename)
    if not os.path.exists(dest_dir):
        shutil.move(source_folder, destination_folder)
    else:
        dst_path = os.path.join(destination_folder, basename)
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source_folder):
            for item in files:
                src_path = os.path.join(root, item)
                if os.path.exists(dst_file):
                    os.remove(dst_file)
                shutil.move(src_path, dst_path)
            for item in dirs:
                src_path = os.path.join(root, item)
                moverecursively(src_path, dst_path)
```

Comment: Your code won't work, the `dst_file` is not defined at all.