# Move the files from different paths and replace if any file already exists

Tags: python, replace, move, shutil

I have list of files like below :

['/home/Test//A/Aa/hello1.c', '/home/Test/C/Aa/hello1.c', '/home/Test/B/Aa/hello1.c']

I'm trying to move all those files from that path to another path. When I find the same filename, I need to replace the existing one as I somehow wanted to remove those files from the existing path, so replace I need to do if same filename exists as they are same files.

Tried as below :

```
import shutil
list_l1 = ['/home/Test//A/Aa/hello1.c', '/home/Test/C/Aa/hello1.c', '/home/Test/B/Aa/hello1.c']
for source in list_l1:
    shutil.move(source, '/home/AShekar/sample_try/sample/')
```

I have received error as 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 292, in move
    raise Error, "Destination path '%s' already exists" % real_dst

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813504/move-and-replace-if-same-file-name-already-exists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move and replace if same file name already exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813504/move-and-replace-if-same-file-name-already-exists)

Comment: No Sorry that scenario is different. Here I have file names too along with the path in the list. Moreover here for each file, the source path is different and also needs to traverse the list

Answer (score 0):

The snippet below will work on Python 3.8

```
    from shutil import copytree, rmtree
    import os
    src = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'src')
    dst = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'dst')
    copytree(src, dst, dirs_exist_ok=True)
    rmtree(src, ignore_errors=True)
```

Comment: No, my scenario didn't work with the copytree method

Comment: Pls. share your directory structure and your expectation.