# Error: Destination path '/home/jupyter/.fastai/data/mnist_sample/train/3/50560.png' already exists

Tags: loops, if-statement

I am trying to move some files from source path to destination path. The program works, the files are able to be moved. But when i run it again to use the "if" statement to check if the files exist - it gets skipped over and goes straight to shutil.move(s, destination) again.

```
source = '/home/jupyter/.fastai/data/mnist_sample/valid/3/'
destination = '/home/jupyter/.fastai/data/mnist_sample/train/3/'

files_to_move = ['50560.png',  '57306.png',  '983.png']

for file in files_to_move:
    s = source + file
    d = destination + file
    print(d)

if s in source:
    print("exist")
    
else:
    print("File is moving")
    shutil.move(s, destination)
    print('Moved:', file)
```

Ideal output after moving the files and running it again

```
exist
exist
exist
```

Output I get as an error

```
File is moving
Error: Destination path '/home/jupyter/.fastai/data/mnist_sample/train/3/50560.png' already exists
```

Comment: Your exists check etc. code is not inside the for loop

Comment: also it seems that you are checking if `s` is in `source` rather than something like if `os.path.exists(d)`

Comment: The function shutil.move(s, destination) will get some problem when there is exist file there. 
Move it after check exist.   
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813504/move-and-replace-if-same-file-name-already-exists