# Move file and overwrite existing in Python 3.6 on Windows

Tags: python, windows, filesystems

For the purpose of safely updating a file, I am writing an updated version to a temporary file and then try to overwrite the original file with it. In a shell unix script I would use `mv FROM TO` for this.

With python on Linux, the functions *os.rename* and *shutil.move* perform an atomic replace operation when the target filename exists. On Windows, they fail.

The behavior can be approximated by a sequence of copy, rename and remove operations, but it cannot be guaranteed, that such a self-written replace operation is performed either finished or completely reverted.

Is it possible to get a reliable “rename and overwrite” operation on Windows?

Comment: See also: [Python - Move and overwrite files and folders - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419665/python-move-and-overwrite-files-and-folders)

Answer (score 2):

As of Python 3.3, the function `os.replace` is available. It should provide cross-platform `mv`-like semantics.

Sadly it fails when trying to move files across file systems.

Even though the documentation says, that *shutil.move* depends on the semantics of *os.rename*, it also works on Windows, *and* supports moving files across file-system boundaries. Sadly, I have seen cases where for some reason it still denied overwriting a file, so when possible, *os.replace* should be safer.