# how to move and overwrite file to another folder in python?

Tags: python

I want to move and overwrite file to another folder which has the same file:

```
d_folder = shutil.move(min_file, d_folder)
print("File is moved successfully to: ", d_folder)
```

Shutil move does not overwrite the file. Is there another way to move and overwrite the file?

```
shutil.Error: Destination path 'C:\\g.txt' already exists
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python)

Comment: See also: [Python - Move and overwrite files and folders - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419665/python-move-and-overwrite-files-and-folders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in a single line, you'll have to do:

```
import os, shutil

if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(d_folder, min_file)):
    os.remove(os.path.join(d_folder, min_file))

d_folder = shutil.move(min_file, d_folder)
print("File is moved successfully to: ", d_folder)
```

This checks if the file already exists, and deletes it if so, then moves the new file to there.