# Moving csv files from source folder after completion of code

Tags: python, path, shutil

I am trying to move the `.csv` files from one folder to another once the code is completed. Tried using multiple solutions like `shutil.move` and `os.replace` and also one of the solutions mentioned in the previous closed posts.

Here is my recent solution:

```
src = "C:\\Manual Upload\\PY Upload\\CC\\"
dest = "C:\Manual Upload\PY Upload"


for f in Path(src).glob("*.csv"):
    shutil.move(os.path.join(src, f), dest)
```

This copies the file to my destination folder, but does not remove it from source and also gives the following error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Manual Upload\\PY Upload\\CC\\QA Finance GRM CONS ASPAC_Cost Center_6698_WI4_2021_CC.csv'
```

I want to delete the `.csv` from source and paste it to destination.

Comment: The CSV isn't open in Excel or some other viewer, is it?

Comment: Also make sure that you're closing the file after you `open(...)` it- I think python will try to open a second (separate) handle to implement `shutil.move(...)`, and if the original hasn't been `.close()`d...

Comment: @Zulfe my bad, it was opened, this code works now. But one problem, If I again paste the same csv in sources, it says file already exists in dest. And also, how to check if csv is open or not?

Comment: @HimanshuPathak Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419665/python-move-and-overwrite-files-and-folders) thread for overwriting the file in the destination if it already exists. Taking a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114492/check-if-a-file-is-not-open-nor-being-used-by-another-process) thread for checking for a file lock before attempting to use it.

Answer (score 0):

This will copy files from one source directory to another one by one

```
import os
import shutil

src = "C:\\Manual Upload\\PY Upload\\CC\\"
dest = "C:\\Manual Upload\\PY Upload\\"

for item in os.listdir(src):
    print(item)
    shutil.copyfile(f"{src}{item}", f"{dest}{item}")
```

credit: [How to copy files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-to-copy-files)